# Issue with quadratically fiting data

Tags: fitting

I have a very weird problem:

I have a data list:

```
list1 = {{2.991592653589793`, 
0.9714808068326763`}, {3.001592653589793`, 
0.9752464325262729`}, {3.0115926535897932`, 
0.9751839638323045`}, {3.021592653589793`, 
0.9751260463868021`}, {3.0315926535897932`, 
0.9750726977562348`}, {3.041592653589793`, 
0.9750239340963618`}, {3.0515926535897933`, 
0.9749797701536178`}, {3.061592653589793`, 
0.9749402192661547`}, {3.0715926535897933`, 
0.9749052933651084`}, {3.081592653589793`, 
0.9748750029754825`}, {3.0915926535897933`, 
0.9748493572170551`}, {3.101592653589793`, 
0.9748283638052356`}, {3.1115926535897933`, 
0.9748120290516745`}, {3.121592653589793`, 
0.9748003578648844`}, {3.1315926535897933`, 
0.9747933537505974`}, {3.141592653589793`, 
0.9747910188121406`}, {3.151592653589793`, 
0.9747933537505988`}, {3.161592653589793`, 
0.9748003578648942`}, {3.171592653589793`, 
0.9748120290516763`}, {3.181592653589793`, 
0.974828363805238`}, {3.191592653589793`, 
0.9748493572170566`}, {3.201592653589793`, 0.9748750029754883`},
{3.211592653589793`, 0.9749052933651294`}, {3.221592653589793`, 
0.9749402192661758`}, {3.231592653589793`, 
0.9749797701536135`}, {3.241592653589793`, 
0.9750239340963711`}, {3.251592653589793`, 
0.9750726977562387`}, {3.2615926535897932`, 
0.9751260463868172`}, {3.271592653589793`, 
0.975183963832316`}, {3.2815926535897932`, 
0.9752464325262769`}, {3.291592653589793`, 0.9714808068327093`}};
```

Then I would like to fit a quadratic function:

```
parabola = Fit[list1, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

howevever, when I compare the list with the fitted function,

```
Show[Plot[parabola , {x, \[Pi] - 0.1, \[Pi] + 0.1}], ListPlot[list1]]
```

I get this:

[image: fitted funtion (solid line), list1 (dots)]

What is wrong here?

Comment: I confirm to see this behavior (Win7, Mma 11.2). I also checked that `FindFit`also gives a paradoxical result with the negative c.

Comment: Have you plotted your `list1` with `PlotRange -> All`? That should show you why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your endpoints are so far of the curve that they do not show up on the plot. These scew the result massively.

```
Fit[list1[[2 ;; -2]], {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

Will return a perfectly exceptable fit (for the remaining data).

Comment: It's quite annoying how Mathematica will sometimes cut off important points from a plot. If you use `Show[Plot[parabola , {x, \[Pi] - 0.1, \[Pi] + 0.1}], ListPlot[list1], PlotRange -> All]`, you can immediately see what's going on.

Comment: I upvoted based on your comment but I should have read the last two lines more carefully(the code and "Will return a perfectly exceptable fit").  One shouldn't toss inconvenient data.  It might be that those two points are the only good ones.